# Android TextView clip beginning of the text with an ellipsis?

Tags: android, textview

Suppose a single-line TextView displays dynamic text, which may be longer than the TextView's width. For example, if a text like the following is too long,

> The answer to your question is Stack Overflow.

by default it will be displayed as

> The answer to your questi...

Is there a built-in way to make it clip the beginning instead, like:

> ...uestion is Stack Overflow.

This is not a Right-to-Left language, I just think the rightmost part is more important.

Comment: You can use marque instead?

Comment: I saw that ellipsize has marquee. It can be useful in some other cases, but for this case, I would prefer start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:ellipsize="start"` as one of your `TextView` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works.

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Hello World! this is android application with large text in textview"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    />
```